# Java SocketException. Why is it closed?

Tags: java, sockets, client

I'm trying to get a threaded chatserver working. But my socket is closing and I have no clue why it is.

In the server class I create a new ClientHandler

```
addHandler(new ClientHandler(this, incoming));
```

addHandler starts the thread and adds the new ClientHandler to an ArrayList in server.
incoming is the client socket.

```
public ClientHandler(Server serverArg, Socket sockArg) {
    server = serverArg;
    client = sockArg;
    System.out.println(client.isClosed());
}
```

There is nothing called between

```
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(client.isClosed());
        in = new Scanner(client.getInputStream());
        out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
        announce();
        System.out.println("Waiting for input");
        boolean done = false;
        while(!done && in.hasNextLine()) {
            System.out.println("There is input!");
            server.broadcast(clientName + ": " + in.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
}
```

When I run this code. This is the output:

```
false
true
java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

Why is it closing immediately after creating this class / before starting it?

Comment: can you copy your full code

Comment: Still have no idea why it didn't work. I fixed it now but it seems like there is nothing changed. Even when I reverse my code to the state above, it still works.

Comment: Things I played with: Implements Runnable, extends Thread in the ClientHandler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is being closed by your code between when you add the handler and when the run() method is called.  I suggest you add a breakpoint to the close method in the JDK and see where it is called. Or have a look at the code after you add the handler.

Comment: This did not eventually fix my code. There was nothing called between the code where I added the handler and were I ran the run() method. But it was the most useful! I think the problem had something to do with threads.

Comment: If you breakpoint the close() method you should see where it is being called.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a networking sniffer like wireshark or tcpdump.

To find out that if the connection broke due to the server side.

I guess that maybe the client side close the connection.

Comment: No. The current application has closed the socket. It has nothing to do with the network, or the peer. Your second and third sentences are mutually contradictory. See @PeterLawrey's answer.